# Import from anywhere in local project directory

Tags: python, import, module, python-module

I am currently working on a object-oriented bigger Project containing multiple self-written sub-modules that I am calling from my main class. Within the sub-modules I am currently importing more modules. This is how  it currently looks:

[] indicates a folder

```
[Project]

> project.py

  > [Module 1]
  > __init__.py
  > module1.py
   > [proxyHandler]
   > __init__.py
   > proxyHandler.py

  > [Module 2]
  > __init__.py
  > module2.py
   > [proxyHandler]
   > __init__.py
   > proxyHandler.py
```

This list goes on for about 10 modules and although the proxyHandler is not 100% the same all the time I think I can make a proxyHandler that handles all cases. Right now I have the proxyHandler folder in each module which I would like to avoid and do the following.

```
[Project]

> project.py

  > [libs]
   > [proxyHandler]
   > __init__.py
   > proxyHandler.py

  > [Module 1]
  > __init__.py
  > module1.py

  > [Module 2]
  > __init__.py
  > module2.py
```

How would I go on about importing it from libs so I dont have copy and paste the proxyHandler in each module. It would also be awesome if the sollution allows for the code to be compiled to an exe using py2exe into a singular file at the end.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run project.py the folder [Project] is added to sys.path. So you can import the module like this

```
from libs import proxyHandler
```

from any module.

Alternatively you can use relative imports:

```
from ..libs import proxyHandler
```

Also yuo can add any folder to sys.path like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(folder)
```

Comment: Thanks this did exactly what I needed. Much appreciated